# Question on Non-Lipschitz Functions

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I have a question about non-Lipschitz functions. Let $f_1,f_2,...f_n$ be some collection of Holder continuous non-Lipschitz scalar functions defined on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. My questions are of the type:

When does there exist a function $h$ s.t $h>0$ and $\sum_i hf_i$ or better all $hf_i$ are Lipschitz or all $hf_i$ are Lipschitz with respect to some of the chosen variables (in case $n>1$)

Any keywords regarding such issues topics or any branches that you know of which studies such things is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Don't you want your $f_i$'s continuous, or at least $\sum f_i$? Since the function $h \cdot (\sum f_i)$ continuous would have the same zero set as $\sum f_i$.

Comment: Sorry yes in fact they can be taken Holder continuous in my case infact

Comment: The sum $\sum f_i$ could just as well be one function $f$, since all we know about this some is that it's Holder. If $f$ is strictly positive, you can just let $h=1/f$.

Comment: Sorry that was the simplest case I had in mind, I forgot to add the others. I think I lack in examples. All examples of non-Lipschitz functions I have in mind are differentiable functions which have singularities on their derivatives (they blowup) and themselves are usually 0 somewhere or functions which are non-Lipschitz on the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ but are Lipschitz on every compact subset. Interesting articles or sources about `non-usual` non-Lipschitz functions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a single function $f$ Lipschitz, one can multiply if by $h(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x,f^{-1}(0)) / f(x)$. (Define $h=1$ on the zero set of $f$. The result is just a signed distance function to the zero set of $f$, which is $1$-Lipschitz.

I would not expect to be able to  do this for two or more functions at once, unless they are tightly related in some way.  It would take some very specific assumptions. It's better to just work with the functions you have than try to come up with a set of conditions.

Finally, I would not expect there to be articles on "how to make a non-Lipschitz function Lipschitz by multiplication". This just does not sound like a topic of a research paper. As a general reference for Lipschitz functions, I find [Lipschitz Analysis](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf) by Heinonen useful.

Comment: Actually similiar but not exactly the same techniques play some role in integrability of continuous distributions and vector fields but the conditions there are a bit more complex (yet more relaxed, some form of weak lipschitz continuity). I am taking this just as a simpler but stronger starting point to think about such things. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Well it seems the stronger condition is not so useful (in the sense that it can not be derived meaningful condition) so I will have to think about the weaker notions. So I take this as the correct answer.